# Google Analytics Tracking with Android App Installs

Tags: android, google-analytics

I need help with some Google Analytics tracking with Android app installs. I've tried researching this but haven't understood it all clearly.

So far, I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name="<IHaveMyPackageNameHere>.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also, I have the following in my InstallReceiver class:

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "InstallReferrerReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
AnalyticsTrackerFactory.setApiKey("");

HashMap<String,String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
try {
    if (intent.hasExtra("referrer")) {
        String referrers[] = intent.getStringExtra("referrer").split("&");
        for (String referrerValue : referrers) {
            String keyValue[] = referrerValue.split("=");
            values.put(URLDecoder.decode(keyValue[0]), URLDecoder.decode(keyValue[1]));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}

Log.d(TAG, "referrer: " + values);
AnalyticsTrackerFactory.getTracker(context).event("Installed", values); } }
```

I've found some of this code online but cannot figure out how to implement it correctly. Basically, I'm stuck at setting an API key and sending the values to Google Analytics.

Can anyone guide me into the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics provides referrer receiver implementation. You don't need to implement it yourself. The instruction for adding campaign attribution are in this dev guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns